# What is the most efficient way to check if given port speaks TLS or not in Java?

Tags: java, ssl, tcp, tls1.2

I know by initiating a full blown TLS handshake you can verify the connection, what i wanted is is there any efficient way i.e sending less no of packets to check if given port speaks TLS or not. I am sort of initializing a client and need to fail fast use non TLS client if the server does not speak TLS.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a plain TCP/IP socket and probe by sending a TLS ClientHello message to the server.  If the server responds with a valid TLS ServerHello, it is reasonable to assume that the server speaks TLS.

However, if your goal is to try TLS and then fall back to non-TLS, then *really* attempting to connect with TLS is probably a better idea than probing.

- If a real client-side TLS stack gets a nonsensical response, it should close the connection immediately and raise an exception.  That should be almost as quick as a TLS probe attempt.
- On the other hand, if you send a probe and get a valid TLS response, the next thing you need to do is to use the client-side TLS stack to connect.  That sends *another* ClientHello.  So, in fact, by probing you will cause *your* use-case to take more time not less time.

Reference:

- [TLS Handshake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_handshake)

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient I suppose would be to send a ClientHello containing a single ciphersuite that nobody supports: CipherSuite `TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5 = { 0x00,0x01 }`. The server should respond with a TLS handshake_failure alert that you can verify.